# How to track/get details about the incoming REST calls from an external application

Tags: marketing-cloud

Where in MC or the way can I get to the details of the JSON data coming in to my SFMC account?

- Consider I have a set of 10 Triggered Send Definitions in place.
  And all of these are being triggered by an External web application, which trigger by using REST API method as below

```
POST /messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{{messagekey}}/send
Host: {{subDomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{authToken}}
```

But I see for some of the emails there are missing fields/parameters.

#### Is there a way in SFMC to check the JSON parameters passed from external application?

So I can figure out the issue is from SFMC or from the external application!

Comment: Switch to [transactional messaging](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/transactional-messaging-api.htm) and you'll have callbacks via [ENS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/ens.htm) to handle this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and make a GET request to the `/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{key}/deliveryRecords` endpoint to determine the status of the send. If there was a failure during deployment, you should see an error message with further info populated in the response.

That being said, it's possible that the error response returned won't be clear enough for you to completely isolate the issue (SFMC error reporting leaves a lot to be desired). To be honest, I'd put the emphasis to validate this issue on the team managing the external application, since they are the ones sending the payload and should be doing validation before making any calls to the platform.

[Link To MDS GET Endpoint Documentation](http:///messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:%7Bkey%7D/deliveryRecords)

Comment: Thanks @Jason Hanshaw ... I will try the above approach and let you know if it gives the debug info I need.

Comment: @ Jason Hanshaw the above give details only about a particular send. But I need the JSON details of all Sends of a particular Triggered Send Definition [both sent n failed].. is this possible... and also curious that can we see the above details within UI is SFMC?